# What is the purpose of using a JavaScript generator in this example?

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6, async-await, koa

I've been reading [Koa.js documentation](http://koajs.com/) which seems like a really cool little platform I'd like to learn more about as I get my feet wet with async/await and other goodies.

Looks like I'm not quite understanding the role of generators in the new JS. I keep running into examples like these:

```
// Using .is()
const minify = require('html-minifier');

app.use(function * minifyHTML(next) {
  yield next;

  if (!ctx.response.is('html')) return;

  let body = ctx.body;
  if (!body || body.pipe) return;

  if (Buffer.isBuffer(body)) body = body.toString();
  ctx.body = minify(body);
});


// Streams
app.use(function * (next) {
  ctx.body = someHTTPStream.on('error', ctx.onerror).pipe(PassThrough());
});
```

**What is the purpose of using a generator here**? I have to admit I understand how they work but absolutely not see the utility here. Are they necessary for async/await to work?

Why isn't the above example:

```
app.use(function(next) {
  ctx.body = 'Hello World';
});
```

Even their Hello World application doesn't do this:

```
app.use(ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello World';
});
```

Comment: Koa does *not* yet use `async`/`await`, it still is stuck with generators (but uses them for the same purpose)

Comment: Koa runs the generators manually, in a way so that the usage of `yield` resembles the behaviour that `await` has natively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generators are used by Koa to execute the next middleware in the sequence.

Koa generators were the method in which Koa handled middleware functions prior to version 2.0.0. Koa 2.x uses async/await instead, which is a new feature to JavaScript.

The middleware shown in your example would look like this in Koa v2:

```
app.use((ctx, next) => {
    await next(); // Execute the next middleware in the sequence

    if (!ctx.response.is('html')) return;

    let body = ctx.body;
    if (!body || body.pipe) return;

    if (Buffer.isBuffer(body)) body = body.toString();
    ctx.body = minify(body);
});
```

Comment: So, next->next->next until it runs out of middleware and then it's if `if (!ctx.response)`?

Comment: next() will go to the next middleware that was specified by the order it was included via app.use. Once the next middleware has completed execution, the middleware that called next() will resume execution. You can imagine it as a recursive stack of middleware calls, where in each layer you have the ability to perform pre processing prior to each middleware call as well as post processing after the resulting middleware call chain has completed execution.

Answer (score 0):

Koa follows the ideology of stacking middleware, thus they provide examples that follow and give emphasis on this ideology.

afaik, middleware is described as a stack and used fifo in terms of code execution.

so on the example you provided, i am reading it as

from first middleware (minifyHTML), the first thing it do is wait for the next middleware/s to finish then proceed with minifying.

but this will not be the case on async/await. the keywords used for generator are `function *() {}` and `yield` or `yield*` while on async/await are basically `async function () {}` and `await`. though they do the same in terms of pausing execution until result is achieved like Promise does.